# Consolibyte Quickbooks PHP SDK (web connector) - Repeated Tasks

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm using the Consolibyte QB SDK [found here](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview), and for the most part is working very well.

However, I have a situation where I need to check if any customers, estimates, and sales orders have been created or updated in Quickbooks each time QB reports to my server.  If so, upload the new/updated ones to the server.

I remember seeing something about scheduled tasks (or repeated tasks, or something of that nature) in the docs, but I cannot find it now.

I don't think I want to bother with Quickbooks SQL Mirroring... seems like overkill.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do what you're describing:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php

In summary:

Register a login success hook - this is a function that gets called every time the Web Connector starts a new sync session.

```
// An array of callback hooks
$hooks = array(
    QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => '_quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess',     // call this whenever a successful login occurs
    );
```

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php#L126

Use the function to queue up a request to query for anything new.

```
function _quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
{
    // For new users, we need to set up a few things
    // Fetch the queue instance
    $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();
    $date = '1983-01-02 12:01:01';

    // Do the same for customers
    if (!_quickbooks_get_last_run($user, QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER))
    {
        _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER, $date);
    }

    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER, 1, QB_PRIORITY_CUSTOMER);
}
```

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php#L219

Write your request/response handlers to create a qbXML query that asks for modified objects:

```
function _quickbooks_customer_import_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    // Iterator support (break the result set into small chunks)
    $attr_iteratorID = '';
    $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Start" ';
    if (empty($extra['iteratorID']))
    {
        // This is the first request in a new batch
        $last = _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action);
        _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action);           // Update the last run time to NOW()

        // Set the current run to $last
        _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $last);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a continuation of a batch
        $attr_iteratorID = ' iteratorID="' . $extra['iteratorID'] . '" ';
        $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Continue" ';

        $last = _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action);
    }

    // Build the request
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerQueryRq ' . $attr_iterator . ' ' . $attr_iteratorID . ' requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <MaxReturned>20</MaxReturned>
                    <FromModifiedDate>' . $last . '</FromModifiedDate>
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                </CustomerQueryRq>  
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}
/** 
 * Handle a response from QuickBooks 
 */
function _quickbooks_customer_import_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
    if (!empty($idents['iteratorRemainingCount']))
    {
        // Queue up another request

        $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER, null, QB_PRIORITY_CUSTOMER, array( 'iteratorID' => $idents['iteratorID'] ));
    }

    ... handle the XML blob from QuickBooks here ... 

    return true;
}
```

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php#L472

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Keith.  Exactly what I was after.